# Enable scroll on page when keyboard is displayed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard, scrollview

My page looks like this:

[image]

If the user focus one of the entries, page is "locked". The user can't move up or down as it follows:

[image]

I've used ContentPage with ScrollView as a main layout. 
I've also tried to set Window.SetSoftInputMode() in various modes, but everything remains the same.

Is there any modular way to fix this (I have workaround with a StackLayout above entries with HeightRequest=0, when one of the entries is focused, I change HeightRequest to the height of keyboard) ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes, something for my specific problem.
Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also manually scroll your page using below code

```
void EntryKeyboardHandle_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var height = SignupGrid.Height;
                await MainScroll.ScrollToAsync(0, height, true);
            });
        }
```

You need to put your grid or stacklayout in scroll view and put focus event on entry.

```
Focused="EntryKeyboardHandle_Focused"
```

Comment: This isn't modular, I would have to change code every time I use this entry, but you gave me an idea how to implement this in Forms project, without adding any code in custom rendereres. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap/) plugin only in your iOS Project (not PCL, not Android), and you iOS Project call:

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.Init();//platform specific init
KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init ();
```

You must do this AFTER you call `Xamarin.Forms.Init().`

[image]

Here are an example: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap/SampleApp

Comment: I was looking for a modular solution, without/or with minimal code in renderers and native projects in general. I'm gonna update this post with my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Added new custom control CustomEntry which is basically default Entry with extended functionality:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entry xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="MyApp.Framework.Controls.CustomEntry"
       TextColor="{StaticResource MainPurple}"
       PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource MainPurpleLight}"
       HeightRequest="45"
       FontSize="14"
       Focused="CustomEntryFocused"
       Unfocused="CustomEntryUnfocused">    
</Entry>
```

And then set Focus and Unfocus methods on this entry:

```
private void CustomEntryFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var stackParent = StackParent as StackLayout;
    stackParent?.Children.Add(new StackLayout() { HeightRequest = `KeyboardHeight });
}

private void CustomEntryUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var stackParent = StackParent as StackLayout;               
    stackParent?.Children.RemoveAt(stackParent.Children.Count - 1);
}
```